# why is it optional to pass jquery reference in require/AMD module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

Why is it optional to pass a reference to jQuery in a requirejs module? For example, consider the following code with different versions of the fist line

```
define(['jquery'],function ($) {

    var initialize=function(){
        console.log($.fn.jquery);
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };

});
```

For this line you would expect the console.log to work

```
define(['jquery'],function ($) { ...
```

'jquery' is loaded and passed to the code that follows with $ as a reference

For this line you would expect the console.log to fail

```
define(function () { ...
```

But why does this line work - ie why does console.log know what $ is

```
define(['jquery'],function () {
```

Now I think you're gonna say ... because you're using the global reference to query of $ but isn't that a bit ... unsafe? And if $ is globally available why do you still need the ['jquery'] dependency also what if you're doing something like this ...

```
define(['jquery','classA','classB] ...
```

If you continue with ...

```
define(['jquery','classA','classB],function(ClassA,ClassB){
```

Then don't you HAVE to include the $ reference otherwise it will think ClassA refers to the ['jquery'] dependency?

So, why is it optional and more importantly, which is best practice?

// EDIT

sorry,  meant to add config details

require.config({

```
paths: {
    "jquery": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min"
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

It should not be thought of as "optional". Always bind the results of AMD modules to parameters.

What is occurring is that jQuery is *not* calling `noConflict` when loaded via AMD in this case so it still clobbers `window.$`. This is why it "works" even if it is not bound to a `$` parameter.

Presumably an AMD shim (or module) would call `noConflict` itself per the wording in the comments at the [end of the source file](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js):

```
// Do this after creating the global so that if an AMD module wants to call
// noConflict to hide this version of jQuery, it will work.
```

Consistently binding jQuery (or any other module, including ones such as jQuery plugins that don't return useful values) to parameters. This will avoid confusion and mismatch in the define lists. (Using multiple versions of jQuery is potentially hazardous.)

Personally, I load jQuery via `<script>` and shim it into an AMD module because I like the control. I also invoke `noConflict` manually so I *need* to access it by the `$` bound as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Although jQuery defines itself as an AMD module, it also exports its `jQuery` and `$` to the global namespace (every module could do it, if they want, but no one does, because that's exactly the opposite of the modularization thing). I don't know what are the advantages, but the seem to think it will help developers that are using hybrid AMD/globals code.

Here's a good explanation of this behavior of jQuery: https://github.com/cujojs/curl/wiki/Using-curl.js-with-jQuery#-and-jquery-are-still-available-as-global-variables